# Sublime Text not responding while code is running

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am using Sublime Repl (Sublime Text 2 or 3, they give the same problems) with Python 2.7 (Canopy, but I tried Anaconda as well, with same problems) and Ipython 2.4.1. I am working on Windows.

I must have messed things up when I updated Ipython (to version 4) and other libraries, and sublime repl was not working properly. I downgraded to Ipython 2.4.1, but I still have some problems:

- auto-completion not working in the repl window
- sublime text often not responding: for example, while the python code is running, and if the python code has some mistakes usually sublime text won't respond anymore at all
- encoding error: this is what an error looks like (I just past a few lines)

  ESC   [1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------ESC[0m
  ESC   [1;31mValueErrorESC   [0m                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  ESC   [1;32mESC

I tried to change the sublime text version, to change version of ipython, to change the python distribution, to delete files related to sublime text and restore it to its original versio, and to look online, but I couldn't find anything useful. Do you have some idea?

Thanks!
Vale

Edit : I don't think it's a duplicate question, as I downgraded again to IPython 2.4... or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks MattDMo, but I don't think it's a duplicate as I am running IPython 2.4 now. I upgraded but than came back to the old version of IPython, do you think something went wrong in the downgrade?